# Parsing a double JSON encoded array in swift and accessing it

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, parsing

I need to parse 10 arrays in an array from JSON to swift and access it. I can fetch the data via a REST API and print it out on the console but I have no idea on how to actually save it to process.

JSON array structure:

```
[[lol_id, lol_time, lol_uid, lol_username, lol_type, lol_url, lol_title, lol_score, lol_comments, lol_badge], 
[lol_id, lol_time, lol_uid, lol_username, lol_type, lol_url, lol_title, lol_score, lol_comments, lol_badge], 
[lol_id, lol_time, lol_uid, lol_username, lol_type, lol_url, lol_title, lol_score, lol_comments, lol_badge], 
[lol_id, lol_time, lol_uid, lol_username, lol_type, lol_url, lol_title, lol_score, lol_comments, lol_badge], 
[lol_id, lol_time, lol_uid, lol_username, lol_type, lol_url, lol_title, lol_score, lol_comments, lol_badge], 
[lol_id, lol_time, lol_uid, lol_username, lol_type, lol_url, lol_title, lol_score, lol_comments, lol_badge], 
[lol_id, lol_time, lol_uid, lol_username, lol_type, lol_url, lol_title, lol_score, lol_comments, lol_badge], 
[lol_id, lol_time, lol_uid, lol_username, lol_type, lol_url, lol_title, lol_score, lol_comments, lol_badge], 
[lol_id, lol_time, lol_uid, lol_username, lol_type, lol_url, lol_title, lol_score, lol_comments, lol_badge], 
[lol_id, lol_time, lol_uid, lol_username, lol_type, lol_url, lol_title, lol_score, lol_comments, lol_badge]]
```

Those arrays basically return integers and strings.

How can I save these in the same style (arrays in array) and access them?

Here is the code I have up until now:

```
@IBAction func buttonLoad(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Setting up the URL 
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://hugelol.com/api/front.php");

    // Request 
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // Prints server response
        println("response = \(response)")

        // Prints the double array 
        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I have tried many different approaches, but have big trouble understanding how exactly to do this. I've also tried swiftyJSON, but I still don't know how to save the data into a swift array. I'm close to banging my head into a wall. Thank you for reading.

Comment: I have such a result with _SwiftyJSON_

`let str = "[[Lol, Lol, Lol], [Lol, Lol, Lol]]"`;

`let data = JSON(str)`;

`println(data); // [[Lol, Lol, Lol], [Lol, Lol, Lol]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of code should provide to you expected results

```
....

    // Setting up the URL
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://hugelol.com/api/front.php");

    // Request
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let jsonString = JSON(data: data).rawString() as String? {
            if let dataFromString = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
// uncomment necessary access method                   
//                    for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
//                        println("Arr = \(subJson)")
//                    }
// OR
//                    println(json[0][0])

            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

....

Comment: Thank you, this prints me out the actual arrays. 

However, I am looking to extract single values out of it in a `json[0][0]` form that gives me the first item in the first array for example.

Comment: I see what do you mean. Actually response is not JSON data, it's just the array with values. JSON has {"key": "value"} format

Comment: Interesting. I thought there might be something wrong with my data: When I tried to print something out for example with: 
`let json = JSON(data: data)
            
            let items = json[0][0]
            
            println(items)`

It just returned `null` or `nil`. I'll be looking into how to solve this, but I have the feeling it could be a big pain. Any suggestions to easing my pain?

Comment: I got an array, let me check it

Comment: check it now, I don't know why it's needed double processing, but it works

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and your patience. Works like a charm now. Well, if it works, it works. Sure I could try and find out why but I'm banging my head against this for a good 10 hours now. Passing on this. I wish I could also vote your answer up but that's not possible since I still have low reputation.

Comment: you are welcome, I voted your question, good luck in your activity

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSJSONSerialization. It will parse JSON and return an NSObject tree.

```
if let result: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil) {...}
```

Comment: How do I use the NSObject tree "result" that this returns?